/api/auth/session being called multiple times and expires getting updated for every call
Integrating NextAuth using Google Provider
[...nextauth].js file
    export const authOptions = {
     providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
       clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
       clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      }),
     ],
     callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account }) {
        
            return true;
        },
        async session ({ session, token }) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken

            return session;
        },
        async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token
                token.id = profile.id
            }

            return token;
        }
     },
     session: {
      strategy: 'jwt',
      maxAge: 4 * 60 * 60
     },
    };
    export default NextAuth(authOptions);

/api/auth/session - this api is being called multiple times. so every times its being called, the expiry times is getting increased leading to permanent sign in.

Kindly let me know how to stop this /api/auth/session being called multiple times?
